# Build CakePHP group by / having query?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp-1.3

I have two tables . USER and entries.
entries table contains start_date and end_date column which contains start and end date for user entries

now i want to retrive data in cake php my postgres query is:

```
select max(end_date) 
from entries 
group by user_id 
having max(end_date) >= current_date
```

How to build it in cakephp

Comment: I fixed your title to describe the actual question. I suggest taking a look at the CakePHP manual and tutorial though - a simple GROUP BY / HAVING query should surely be covered? I haven't used CakePHP, so to help you I'd just have to go read the manual too.

Comment: Thanx Craig Ringer, but in cakephp 1.2 group by clause is not working .